# Java JNI: Bad values in primitive (double) array set within C++

Tags: java, c++, memory-management, java-native-interface

I am trying to set a primitive double array field of a Java object from within C++ code. The Java object is defined as:

```
public class EmitterTrack {
  public int trackNumber;
  public long lastUpdatedTime;
  public int associatedEmitterModeTrackNumber;

  public EmitterObservationStruct updatedEmitterObservation;

  public double[] emitterTypeProbabilities;

  public EmitterTrack() {
    emitterTypeProbabilities = new double[9];
    updatedEmitterObservation = new EmitterObservationStruct();
  }
}
```

The C++ code that is creating a new EmitterTrack object and attempting to set the double array looks like:

```
void sendEmitterTracksToJava(jclass javaEmitterTrackClass, JNIEnv *jniEnv, EmitterTrack emitterTrack) {
  jmethodID ctor = jniEnv->GetMethodID(javaEmitterTrackClass, "<init>", "()V");

  jobject javaEmitterTrack = jniEnv->NewObject(javaEmitterTrackClass, ctor, NULL);

  jfieldID fid = jniEnv->GetFieldID(javaEmitterTrackClass, "emitterTypeProbabilities", "[D");
  jintArray jary;
  jary = (jintArray)jniEnv->GetObjectField(javaEmitterTrack, fid);
  jint *intArray = jniEnv->GetIntArrayElements(jary, 0);

  for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    intArray[j] = emitterTrack.emitterTypeProbabilities[j];
  }

  jniEnv->ReleaseIntArrayElements(jary, intArray, 0);
}
```

When I pass the Java emitter track object back to Java I'm seeing output like this:

```
Emitter Track:
  emitterTypeProbabilities[0]: 2.12199579097E-313
  emitterTypeProbabilities[1]: 6.3659873739E-313
  emitterTypeProbabilities[2]: 1.06099789568E-312
  emitterTypeProbabilities[3]: 1.48539705397E-312
  emitterTypeProbabilities[4]: 3.95E-322
  emitterTypeProbabilities[5]: 0.0
  emitterTypeProbabilities[6]: 0.0
  emitterTypeProbabilities[7]: 0.0
  emitterTypeProbabilities[8]: 0.0
```

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong that I'm just not seeing?

Comment: What values are you expecting? Those sure look like floating-point rounding errors to me...

Comment: Shouldn't you use jdoubleArray instead of jintArray?

Comment: Oh, for crying out loud!! Thank you SO much...I have been staring at this forever and it never occurred to me. I feel like an idiot now but it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Sir RoTN nailed it! I was stupidly using jintArray and getting/releasing int arrays as opposed to double. Replacing with the following fixes everything:

```
jdoubleArray jary;
jary = (jdoubleArray)jniEnv->GetObjectField(javaEmitterTrack, fid);
jdouble *doubleArray = jniEnv->GetDoubleArrayElements(jary, 0);

for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
  doubleArray[j] = emitterTrack.emitterTypeProbabilities[j];
}

jniEnv->ReleaseDoubleArrayElements(jary, doubleArray, 0);
```